# Differentiating public API responses from authenticated API responses

Tags: http, http-status-codes

I'm building an API which I would like to utilize in both my web app and on a public facing website. It's behavior simple:

1. If an authenticated request is made, return all data for the resource(s).
2. If an unauthenticated request is made, return public/published data for the resource(s).

I figured I would look into using status codes to differentiate the responses based on the two behaviors above instead of utilizing metadata in the response.

**Is it acceptable to use a status code of 200 for the first behavior and 206 for the second behavior?**

It's unclear to me if 206 is used properly in this instance according to http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Is it acceptable to use a status code of 200 for the first behavior and 206 for the second behavior?**

No, it is not acceptable.  `206 Partial Content` is the status given in response to *explicit requests* for some particular range of bytes from  the full response.  As documented under [section 10.2.7](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.2.7):

> The request MUST have included a Range header field ([section 14.35](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35)) indicating the desired range

In your case, an "unauthenticated request" will not *per se* include a Range header and therefore a 206 response would violate the specification.